# Vertx : cannot read SQLConnection from fillReport

Tags: jasper-reports, vert.x, vertx3

I want to use vertx and JasperReports, I create my connection and I test it, everything is ok, but when I want to fill jasper report by using fillReport method (where the last one is Connection) it shows error :

> The method fillReport(JasperReport, Map< String,Object >, Connection) in the type JasperFillManager is not applicable for the arguments (JasperReport, null, Class < connection>).

Any idea how should I cast my SQLConnect to connect ?

Here is my code :

```
   AsyncSQLClient client = MySQLClient.createShared(vertx, mySQLClientConfig);
   client.getConnection(res -> {
         if (res.succeeded()) {
                  SQLConnection connection = res.result();
                  try{
              String report = "C:\\Users\\paths\\Test1.jrxml";
              JasperReport Jasp = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report);
              JasperPrint JASP_PRINT = JasperFillManager.fillReport(Jasp, null, connection);
              JasperViewer.viewReport(JASP_PRINT);                          
                      }
                  catch(Exception ex){System.out.println(ex);}
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple. You can't cast a Vert.x `io.vertx.ext.sql.SQLConnection` to a JDBC `java.sql.Connection`.

Vert.x heavily relies upon asynchronous calls. JDBC is blocking and so Vert.x wraps it with an asynchronous interface (and a bit more). There is no way to get to the real `java.sql.Connection` as there is no getter or something like that in the [`JDBCConnectionImpl`](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-jdbc-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/ext/jdbc/impl/JDBCConnectionImpl.java) or in the `SQLConnection` interface.

That doesn't mean you can't use Jasper with Vert.x. You need to open you own JDBC connection – but don't [block the Event loop](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#golden_rule)! So I suggest you have a look at the [Worker Verticles](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#worker_verticles), which don't block the Event loop because they spin up a separat thread.

Comment: Thank you for your reply  @alexvetter so there is no way to use vert.x with jasper report ?

Comment: Editied my answer. Hope it now answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for help, I will take a look on Workers, have a good day @alexvetter

Comment: If you feel like your question is solved I hope you accept my answer, otherwise I'm happy to elaborate the usage of Worker Verticles a bit.